# Control on an algebraic excersise

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I used basic algebra to go from:
$$\tan ⁡2\beta=\frac{2[(\tan⁡\gamma/\tan\alpha)-x\tan⁡\gamma][(ba+bc)+x(b^2+c^2)]}{(a+bx)^2+(b+cx)^2-(b^2+c^2)[(\tan\gamma/\tan\alpha)-x\tan\gamma]^2}
$$
to
$$
x^2{(b^2+c^2)[(1-\tan^2\gamma)(\frac{1}{2}\tan2\beta)+\tan\gamma]}+x[(ab+bc)(\tan2\beta+\tan\gamma)+(b^2+c^2)(\tan\gamma/\tan\alpha)(\tan\gamma\tan2\beta-1)]+{[a^2+b^2-(b^2+c^2)(\tan\gamma/\tan\alpha)^2](\frac{1}{2}\tan2\beta)-(\tan\gamma/\tan\alpha)(ba+bc)}=0
$$
where my objective was to obtain a quadratic equation to solve for $x$. However, in a textbook I find that starting from the same initial form of the equation, they reach:
$$
x^2(b^2+c^2)\tan^2\alpha[\tan2\beta(1-\tan^2\gamma)-2\tan\gamma]-2x\{\tan2\beta[(ba+bc)\tan^2\alpha-(b^2+c^2)\tan^2\gamma\tan\alpha]-\tan\gamma\tan\alpha[(ab+bc)\tan\alpha+b^2+c^2]\}+\tan2\beta[(a^2+b^2)\tan^2\alpha-(b^2+c^2)\tan^2\gamma]-2(ab+bc)\tan\alpha\tan\gamma=0
$$
which gives different results for $x$. Therefore, I am not sure if I made a mistake that I can't find, or the textbook is wrong (e.g. typo). I will appreciate if anyone can help me with this. As clarification, the angles ($\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\alpha$) are just constants, as well as factors $a,b,c$.

Comment: Michael Rosenberg will solve this!

Comment: are you interested to see a full solution?

Comment: No, I only want to know If my version of the equation is ok, or the textbook version is ok. Wen I give real values to all the constants, applying baskhara gives different results for x en each case, therefore one of the equations (mine or the textbook's) must be wrong.

Comment: There are several places where your meaning is not completely clear ($\tan \gamma x$ means $x\tan\gamma$? $\tan 2\beta/2$ means $\frac{1}{2}\tan 2\beta$?)

Comment: How did you get rid of the $\tan  (\gamma  x)$ and end up with a quadratic polynomial in $x$ ?

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear: $\tan\gamma x$ means $x\tan\gamma$ and $\tan2\beta/2$ means $(1/2)(\tan2\beta)$. I will edit the equation accordingly

Comment: Are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ related in any way? For example, are these the sides and angles of a triangle?

Comment: @rogerl they are related but not like in a triangle, indeed the first form of the equation is the one that relates them. If you wanna know $x$, you must know those three angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take your solution and multiply both sides by $2\tan^2\alpha$, you get for the coefficient of $x^2$
$$(b^2+c^2)\tan^2\alpha[\tan2\beta(1-\tan^2\gamma)+2\tan\gamma],$$
which is the same except for the final sign as the book solution.

Similarly, the linear term becomes the same as in the book solution except for a couple of signs.

The constant term becomes identical to the constant term in the book solution.

That doesn't resolve which one is incorrect, but it may help you find your error (if there is one).

Edit: After doing the arithmetic myself, I get the same thing you got.

Comment: thank you, at least I have an independent check on my solution, although as you say I still don't know were that multiplying factor comes from. thanks again

Comment: I'm assuming that the multiplying factor comes in if you decide to clear fractions in the original equation by multiplying through by $\tan^2\alpha$. Of course multiplying through by $2\tan^2\alpha$ doesn't change the values of $x$, but the authors clearly made an arithmetic error somewhere else (or the posted equation was incorrect).